# How to map the keypad (NUM) keys in vim?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, vim, putty

I am using Vim version 7.4 from 2012-Dez-06 of Ubuntu 16.04 and I use PuTTY 0.67 on W10. I want to map the keys of the NUM keypad in `.vimrc`. I tried on the command line in vim but it doesn't work:

```
map <k1> COMMAND
map k1 COMMAND
map <C-k1> COMMAND
map <S-k1> COMMAND
map *keypad-1* COMMAND
map keypad-1 COMMAND
```

If I do for example:

```
map 1 dd
```

it works and the line is deleted if I hit `1`.

If I hit in vi the NUM keypad buttons `1`, `2`, `3` ... I get `q`, `r`, `s`, `t` ... If I map `q` to a command only the normal `q` button will execute the command but not `1` on the NUM keypad.
My `.vimrc` is:

```
# cat ~/.vimrc
syntax on
set t_Co=256
colorscheme elflord
if &diff
    colorscheme apprentice
endif
```

`h keycodes` tells me:

```
…
<kHome>         Anfang auf dem Ziffernblock (oben links)*keypad-home*
<kEnd>          Ende auf dem Ziffernblock (unten links) *keypad-end*
                                                        *keypad-page-up*
<kPageUp>       Bild rauf auf dem Ziffernblock (oben rechts)
                                                        *keypad-page-down*
<kPageDown>     Bild runter auf dem Ziffernblock (unten rechts)
<kPlus>         + auf dem Ziffernblock                  *keypad-plus*
<kMinus>        - auf dem Ziffernblock                  *keypad-minus*
<kMultiply>     * auf dem Ziffernblock                  *keypad-multiply*
<kDivide>       / auf dem Ziffernblock                  *keypad-divide*
<kEnter>        Enter auf dem Ziffernblock              *keypad-enter*
<kPoint>        Dezimalzeichen auf dem Ziffernblock     *keypad-point*
<k0> - <k9>     0 bis 9 auf dem Ziffernblock            *keypad-0* *keypad-9*
<S-...>         Umschalttaste                   *shift* *<S-*
<C-...>         Steuerungstaste                 *control* *ctrl* *<C-*
<M-...>         Alt-Taste oder Meta-Taste       *meta* *alt* *<M-*
<A-...>         dasselbe wie <M-...>            *<A-*
<D-...>         Befehlstaste (nur Macintosh)    *<D-*
<t_xx>          Taste mit dem Eintrag »xx« in der TermCap
```

Therefore `<k1>` should be correct.

I am using Putty with ssh and the folowing keyboard setting:

[image]
How can I map the keys of the numeric key pad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default settings of PuTTY are just fine. Do not change anything in `PuTTY-> Terminal -> Keyboard` (see above) or disable in `PuTTY-> Terminal -> Features` anything:

[image]

You can map in vi the NUM keys in the following way:

```
inoremap <Esc>Oq 1
inoremap <Esc>Or 2
inoremap <Esc>Os 3
inoremap <Esc>Ot 4
inoremap <Esc>Ou 5
inoremap <Esc>Ov 6
inoremap <Esc>Ow 7
inoremap <Esc>Ox 8
inoremap <Esc>Oy 9
inoremap <Esc>Op 0
inoremap <Esc>On .
inoremap <Esc>OQ /
inoremap <Esc>OR *
inoremap <Esc>Ol +
inoremap <Esc>OS -
inoremap <Esc>OM <Enter>
```

This setting is an example for using the NUM key as they should be. Of course you can change the mappings as usual.